# SSRS Data driven subscription 'Pending' Status

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an error listing report which shows me how many subscriptions have failed or pending. I just discovered that I have around 10 pending subscriptions with 'Pending' status. I am not completely sure what Pending really means. I tried to look through SSRS LogFiles and there is an account related message:

> SSRS LogFiles w WARN: IsAdmin check for the account MyAccount returns
>   false because this account has no membership. It is possibly a group
>   account.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only solutions I've seen are [changing the subscription owner](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/andy_warren/2015/07/01/reporting-services-subscriptions-in-pending-status/) or rebooting the machine.